# sql to query to Magento query

Tags: magento-1.9, sql, query

How should I convert following sql statement into magento statement.

```
select value from customer_address_entity_varchar where attribute_id = 143 and entity_id = 567;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do that with below query

```
    $connectionresource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
    $readconnection = $connectionresource->getConnection('core_read');
    $allrecord = $readconnection->select()->from(array('customer'=>'customer_address_entity_varchar'),array('customer.value'))->where('customer.attribute_id=?', 143)->where('customer.entity_id=?', 567);
    $alldata =$readconnection->fetchOne($allrecord);
    echo $alldata;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
    echo "<pre>";
$result = array();
$read = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read'); 
$result = $read->fetchAll('select value from customer_address_entity_varchar where attribute_id = 143 and entity_id = 567');
print_r($result);
```